# Google map distance based clustering

Tags: google-maps, cluster-analysis, distance

I need to group addresses together which are within 4KM area and came to know that Google maps distance based clustering can be used for that but there no public library available for that. What other options are available.

Comment: Implement it yourself, and come back here when you have an actual programming question with that. **questions for off-site resources are off-topic**.

Comment: Here is an example of distance based clustering: http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~sulcmila/markersdc/example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In finding points to cluster, you can use the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate distance from a point. Or, you can try using an open-source search engine like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which gives you radius search out of the box.

Comment: Thanks dear...will do that and come back to you folks